# Move closest automatic horizontal pagebreak up to keyword line

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clean up how automatic horizontal page breaks fall on my worksheet. If the automatic page break does not break above the phrase "Overall Status" in column 'D' I would like to move the next closest horizontal page break below "Overall Status" up.  Below is a code snippet that places a horizontal page break above all lines that say "Overall Status" in column D, but that is way too many page breaks.

```
Sub Pagebreak()
'adds horizontal pagebreak before every 'Overall Status'

Dim Search As String

Search = "Overall Status"

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set c = .Find(What:=Search, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=c
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If

    'Then try toggle between pagebreak screen and normal view
    End With
End Sub
```

The snippet of code below shows where the existing horizontal page break currently falls:

```
Sub HPageBreakTest()
'counts and shows where horizontal pagebreaks are
Dim pgeBreak As HPageBreak

With ActiveSheet
.Cells(65536, 1).Select
MsgBox .HPageBreaks.Count & " Horizontal page breaks counted"
For Each pgeBreak In .HPageBreaks
MsgBox "pgbreak at row: " & pgeBreak.Location.row
.Cells(65536, 1).Select
Next pgeBreak
.Cells(1, 1).Select
End With

End Sub
```

I would like to figure out how I can combine the logic of these two code snippets, to (1) locate the first automatic horizontal page break below "Overall Status" and (2) move that page break up just above "Overall Status" phrase in column D.  Not a horizontal page break for each instance of "Overall Status."  I hope my question makes sense.  Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, my suggested change would insert a page break on the first occurrence of "Overall Status" before the first natural pagebreak. You want to insert before the last occurrence before a page break. The complication is that as soon as you enter a manual page break all the other breaks change.
So loop through the range of the first page to find the last occurrence
insert page break
repeat for all other pages

the range in column D for a page n is given by the row of the last page break +1 to the row of the next page break so

```
 Dim Search As String
 Search = "Overall Status"
 Dim x as long
 Dim r as range
 dim lastrow as long

 with activesheet
     do while x < .hpagebreaks.count
           for each r in range("D" & (lastrow+1) & ":D" & .HPageBreaks(x+1).Location.Row)
              if r = search then     'might have found it
                  lastrow = r.row  'so remember the row number
              end if
           next r
           if lastrow = 0 then exit sub  'no find  
           .hpagebreaks.add before:=range("A" & lastrow)

           x = x +1
      loop
 end with
```

Comment: Thanks, Harassed Dad!  I just tried your solution out (above) and it appears to work the treat!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

with

```
 With Activesheet.range("D1:D" & HPageBreaks(1).Location.Row)
```

(Note this assumes that there is at least one pagebreak)

Comment: Thanks, but the above code works fine, I am trying to figure out how to maybe use these snippets to find the closet natural page break below the last "Overall Status" in column D and move the hor. page break up for each instance to the end of column D.